# How to attach a event to a variable in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to implement Sip.js on my project. I have created a session variable and stored the session in that , but now I need to track an event on that session variable to attach audio on DOM. How do I add a event listener on a variable.

Here is how my code look like:

```
<template>
  <div> <button @click="callme">Call Me</button></div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
      return {
          session: null,
          ua : null,
          }
      },
   methods: {
      callme(){
                this.session = this.ua.invite('sip:bob@example.com')   
        },
     },
  created(){
        this.ua= new SIP.UA({
                   uri: 'bob@example.onsip.com',
                   transportOptions: {
                    wsServers: ['wss://sip-ws.example.com']
                   },
                   authorizationUser: '',
                   password: ''
                  });
    }
   }

</script>
```

Now I need to listen for :

```
session.on('trackAdded', function() {

}
```

where do I can add this , whenever trackAdded on the session this function will run?

Here is the attach media option as per the documentation https://sipjs.com/guides/attach-media/

Comment: watch `session` and do it when `session` changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`session` and `ua` should not set in `data()` - they should not be tracked by Vue. [They are not plain data objects](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data):

> The data object for the Vue instance. Vue will recursively convert its
> properties into getter/setters to make it “reactive”. **The object must
> be plain:** native objects such as browser API objects and prototype
> properties are ignored. A rule of thumb is that data should just be
> data - it is not recommended to observe objects with their own
> stateful behavior.

That being said, if you must insist, you could set up a handler right after the session is created as follows:

```
methods: {
    trackAddedEventHandler() {
        console.log('trackAdded Event!');
    },
    callme() {
        this.session = this.ua.invite('sip:bob@example.com');
        session.on('trackAdded', this.trackAddedEventHandler);
    },
},
```

But really do test those behaviors, as you may rely on something that Vue may not support when the object is at `data()`.

Comment: I have removed session and ua from the data() , defined it as a global var on script. Thank you!